# Elegantly concantenating std::string_view and string literal into a std::string

Tags: c++, string-view

Assume I have the following function:

```
std::string greeting(const std::string_view name){
    return std::string(name) + " we wish you a very nice day and week and month and year";
}
```

It works fine, but I want to avoid more than 1 memory allocation, assuming name is too long to fit into SSO buffer. So I came up with this:

```
std::string greeting_efficient(const std::string_view name){
    constexpr std::string_view suffix = " we wish you a very nice day and week and month and year";
    std::string result;
    result.reserve(name.size()+suffix.size());
    result+=name;
    result+=suffix;
    return result;
}
```

AFAIK it works but it is quite ugly, is there a easier way to do this?

I am fine with using C++20/23 if solution needs it.

Comment: just use `std::format` (since C++20) or fmt library. And most important thing when taking about efficiency: write performance test and measure every solution you think is worth trying.

Answer (score 3):

You could use `std::format` which is a `C++20` feature. Or you could pull in the [fmt](https://github.com/fmtlib/fmt) library which is what `std::format` is based off of if your compiler hasn't implemented `std::format` yet.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <format>
#include <string>


static std::string greeting(std::string_view name)
{
    return std::format("{} have a very nice day", name);
}

int main() 
{
    std::cout << greeting("Bill") << '\n';
}
```

You could also use an `std::stringstream` as well, but I'm unsure how efficient it is.

```
static std::string greeting(std::string_view name) 
{
    std::ostringstream os{};
    os << name << " have a very nice day";
    return os.str();
}
```

Comment: `std::stringstream` is slow since it uses `std::string` without `reserve`, so as it grows it has to reallocate buffer.

Comment: is fmt:: guaranteed to not allocate more than once?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if it's more elegant or not, but this should assure that there's only one allocation:

- Initialize the `std::string` with the correct size instead of default constructing it and reserving space. Expected effects:

  - (+) It makes the one allocation directly at construction.
  - (+) The string's internal *size* counter will not be changed in the rest of the process.
  - (-) It initializes the memory with the character of your choice.
- Copy `name` directly into the string's memory.
- Copy `suffix` directly into the string's memory.

  - Both copy operations needed should be using the fastest copying available. Two `memcpy`s or `memmove`s will likely be the result.

```cpp
#include <algorithm>

std::string greeting(std::string_view name){
    static constexpr std::string_view suffix = " we wish you a very nice day"
                                               " and week and month and year";

    std::string rv(name.size() + suffix.size(), '\0'); // one allocation

    std::copy(suffix.begin(), suffix.end(),
              std::copy(name.begin(), name.end(), rv.begin()));

    return rv;
}
```